# I wonder how to multiple this sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series

If I have two sequences: $$a_n=\{n|n\le5,n\in N\}$$ $$b_n=\{n|n\le2,n\in N\}$$
So $a_n$ members are $a_1=1,a_2=2,a_3=3,a_4=4,a_5=5$ and thats it.
And $b_n$ members are $b_1=1,b_2=2$ and thats it.
So what will be the members of: $$a_nb_n$$
Basicly I get $a_nb_n=\{n^2|n\le?,n\in N\}$
One has $\le2$ and the other $\le5$ so which one to take?

I'm trying to find an example for:
$$\sup\{a_nb_n|n\in N\}< \sup\{a_n|n\in N\}\sup\{b_n|n\in N\}$$
$$a_n,b_n\ge0$$

Comment: They are not sequences. They just contain finitely many terms

Comment: @CheungSW So it means I cant multiple them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your notation is not helping you. Write

$$A = \{n| n\leq 5\} \ \ \ \text{ and  } \ \ B = \{ n|n\leq 2\}. $$

Then we can define a "product" $A\cdot B$ by

$$A\cdot B = \{ n| n = ab\text{ for some }a\in A, b\in B\}$$

Is that what you want?

Comment: I was trying to find an example where $\sup\{a_nb_n|n\in N\}< \sup\{a_n|n\in N\}\sup\{b_n|n\in N\}$ and thought to use weird sequences like that

Comment: @TheOne: Note that as Cheung SW said in the comment, they are not sequence, they are just a connection of elements in $\mathbb N$. So let me ask you: What do you mean by a sequence?

Comment: Ordered list of items from n=1 to n=something which applies to a logic of a certain function

Comment: @TheOne: Ok, so in this case, $a_n = n$ for $n=1, \cdots, 5$, and $b_n = n$ for $n=1, 2$. So $a_n b_n$ REALLY has no definition for $n=3, 4, 5$. So if you wanna consider a product of the form you mentioned, then both sequences should ends at the same $n$.

Comment: Can you think of an example on which: $\sup\{a_nb_n|n\in N\}< \sup\{a_n|n\in N\}\sup\{b_n|n\in N\}$?

Comment: For example, when $a_1 = 1$, $a_2 = 0$, $b_1 = 0$, $b_2 = 1$. @TheOne

Comment: Can I define a sequence like that? because I'm really confused about what makes a sequence a sequence

Comment: Like you said, a sequence is really an ordered list of items. The ordered can be chosen. So we have choose $a_n =n$ like what you did, but can also choose $a_n = 2n$ for example.

Comment: Note also that the order is important: The finite sequence $a_1 = 1$, $a_2= 2$ is not the same as $a_1 = 2$, $a_2 = 1$. (Though the "items" they takes are the same. @TheOne

Comment: So we can say that $a_n$ is a sequence in which $a_1=1,a_2=2$ and thats it, no $a_3$ and no "function" that we can define $a_n=xxx$

Comment: I think so, everything is defined by you. But let me clarify here. Most of the time when we math ppl say of a sequence, the ordered list start from $n=1$ up to all $n$. So we will say for example $a_1=1$, a_2 = 3$ a FINITE sequence to distinguish from the usual definition.

Comment: Thanks I think I'm allowed to use finite sequences as well

Answer (score 1):

You can take the [tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Definition):
$$(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)\otimes(1,2)=(1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 6, 4,8,5,10).$$

Comment: Normally there should be some algebraic structure when defining tensor product. Seems that this is not what the OP asks for.

Comment: @John It's not really clear what OP asks for. He speaks of sequences, yet he writes sets in his post. I just treat his sequences as matrices and then this makes sense.